# g++ link problems: In function `_start': (.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'

Tags: c++, linker, g++

I am getting an undefined reference to main error - even though I have defined main, and (AFAICT), I have linked it correctly. Here is my code and the commands I used:

```
// ################################################
//proj1.h
#ifndef  __SCRATCH_PROJ1_H
#define  __SCRATCH_PROJ1_H

int addOne(int i);

#endif /*__SCRATCH_PROJ1_H */

// ################################################

//proj1.cpp
#include "proj1.h"

int addOne(int i){
    return i+1;
}


// ################################################
//proj1_unittest.cpp

#include "proj1.h"
#include "gtest/gtest.h"

// Test Function
TEST(addOneTest, Positive) {
    EXPECT_EQ(1,addOne(0));            
    EXPECT_EQ(2,addOne(1));            
    EXPECT_EQ(40320, addOne(40319));   
}

TEST(addOneTest, Negative) {
    EXPECT_FALSE(addOneTest(-1));      
}


GTEST_API_ int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

Here is the console output:

```
$ g++ -isystem -pthread -c ${SOURCE_DIR}/proj1.c -o ${SOURCE_DIR}/proj1.o
$ g++ -o ${SOURCE_DIR}/mytest ${SOURCE_DIR}/*.o -L${GTEST_DIR} libgtest.a 
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Why is the `main()` function not been found by the linker?

Comment: What does GTEST_API_ resolve to?

Comment: Is it gtest in your current project directory?

Comment: Also, note that you need to give the input to the linker the `gtest` libs which has `gtest.lib` and `gtest_main.lib`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can see you are not compiling file proj1_unittest.cpp (as your code comment has it) / proj1_unittest.c (as your console output implies).

Comment: Yup, I forgot to compile the .cpp file which contained the main :(